# Import a .json file to redis db via redis-py

Tags: python, json

Say I have this json code

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

How could I store it to a redisdb via `redis-py`?

My code is the following (I believe it's wrong):

```
import json
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=1)
with open('json_test.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    test_data = json.loads(data_file.read())
r.hmset('test_json', test_data)
```

Comment: There is some reason why you are using hmset? Your goal is store full document under a single key?

Comment: No, I want to make an optimal storage of this .json file. My general goal is to store .json files in redis (and larger files than the one I gave)  with the best possible structure (via redis-py).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering your code, and simplicity of requirement: Store JSON file content on redis, your can use simple SET for it.

To improve data parsing, it is not necessary to use `.read()` method over file pointer, consequently, you use `json.load(fp)` method version.

```
import json
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=1)
with open('json_test.json') as data_file:
    test_data = json.load(data_file)
r.set('test_json', test_data)
```